# SameSite cookie not passed in background call

Tags: javascript

I have a cookie for `domain1.com`. When I'm making a background call (using JS) to `domain1.com`, from another domain, `domain2.com`, the cookie is not passed. But when I call `domain1.com` from the browser, the cookie is passed as expected.

This is the code snippet used to make call to `domain1`:

```
reqwest({
    url: dataUrl,
    method: 'get',
    crossOrigin: true,
    withCredentials: true,
    success: res => {
        //
    },
    error: err => {
        //
    }
});
```

Comment: Exactly how are you making a "background call"?

Comment: Could you provide a code sample?

Comment: Background call is essentially made using JavaScript. It's a static site built using React.

Comment: If you don't post **specifics** about how you're making the call, you can't expect much help.

Comment: The code should be posted **in the question**, not in a comment. `reqwest()` is not a basic API. We have to know **exactly** how you're making the HTTP request in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure your cookie is with SameSite: Lax or None (See on Chrome). If you'r using Lax (or Nothing) ensure that you're doing a GET request

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite

Comment: But does it need to be Lax since I'm using the cookie with the same domain? The only difference is now I'm calling it in JavaScript of another domain site instead of the address bar.

Comment: you posted a link to the French language site

Comment: fixed it to the english equivalent